# Split data to smaller pieces then encrypt with RSA

Tags: cryptography, rsa, encryption

I am working on something which requires a large piece of data to be encrypted.

I know that this should be done using a symmetric key encryption system like AES instead of a public key encryption system like RSA, but I am thinking of doing it with RSA anyway, by splitting the data into smaller pieces and then encrypting each of them with the same public key.

Aside from performance considerations, is this method safe? Can this encryption method be broken easily?

Comment: This question would be a better fit for http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Especially since there is a lot to be desired from the answers you are getting - please disregard any answer as they are *likely* to be incorrect (even if they have been upvoted).

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not secure.

You are essentially using RSA as a block cipher, as you already noted by
saying that you should probably be using a symmetric cipher in this place.

Also, as noted by @Jamey, this scheme of encrypting chunks/blocks of the
plaintext independently from one another is, essentially, like Electronic
Code Book ([ECB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29)) mode of operation of a block cipher.

Without the use of anything else, your proposed scheme is vulnerable to, at
least, two attacks:

- a [replay attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack), if you don't include any additional information in
  your scheme to prevent reuse of the messages.  Think, for example, of an
  attacker recording all the encrypted stream between Alice and a Bank,
  where she withdraws $100.00 from her account.

  In this case, by replaying the stream more than one time, the attacker can
  make Alice go bankrupt by sending the stream many times to the bank, which
  will be fine.
- a [chosen-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack), as the blocks are independent and the
  attacker's [advantage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advantage_%28cryptography%29) in this case would be 1 (as high as one can get).

Really, it is fun to try to come up with one's own cipher, but getting the
security right is tough. Even more without integrity/authentication.

---

**NOTE:** Since it seems that people miss a lot the part "Without the use of anything else" of my original post, my answer keeps getting downvoted.

I guess that I should make it clear that the above is about the use of "pure RSA" or "textbook RSA", which does not include random padding (the "anything else") for the use of an RSA cipher.

In real applications, the *"anything else"* is the use of [OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_Asymmetric_Encryption_Padding) (a "stronger form" of [simple padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Padding_schemes) the original message with random bits), as incorporated in newer versions of the [PKCS#1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_%E2%99%AF1) standard.

Comment: Replay attacks are as likely for symmetric ciphers as for asymmetric ciphers. RSA PKCS#1 encryption uses random padding, so ECB attacks won't work. Otherwise you would not be able to encrypt multiple messages with the same key. I don't think choosen plaintext attacks work either, but I'll have to get my brain thinking straight before I can *conclude* anything about that.

Comment: @owlstead, you probably didn't notice me saying the part of "without the use of anything else" which means that my answer was about "pure RSA" (aka "textbook RSA), without padding (the "anything else").

Comment: According to the specs, the padding is an integral part of RSA encryption. If you remove the padding then you would have to prove the security of the new scheme - in other words, anything that uses RSA without padding and a new security proof is insecure *period*.

Answer (score 0):

The general advice is this: Don't invent a new cryptosystem if you actually care about security; or if you must, at least get it publicly peer reviewed by serious cryptography researchers.

That said, the best I've got is that this sounds like you're treating RSA as a kind of block cipher, and so you probably want to use a standard block cipher mode. The obvious thing to do, of just encrypting each block separately with the same key, sounds equivalent to Electronic Code-Book (ECB) mode, which is not secure. Perhaps you can use one of the better modes like CBC with RSA?

Since we're ignoring the practical performance problems, I'll point out a different practical consideration. The input `m` to RSA must be in the range 0<=`m`<`n`, where `n` is one of the public key parameters. Since the value of `n` must be the product of two distinct primes, it can never be a power of 2, so dividing your larger message into chunks that fit in the input to RSA is a little confusing.

Also, don't forget about padding each message you encrypt with RSA.

In short: Don't do it for a real project, but it's a neat thought experiment. :-)

Comment: See my comment on jbrito's answer.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use publicly vetted APIs you should be fine. But generally, you will want to encrypt just a symmetric key (like AES) with a RSA public key and then block-encrypt each message fragment with that symmetric key.

Comment: This is not correct, as one can use the APIs in an incorrect way. See, for example: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf

Comment: So as a curiosity, are you aware of crypto APIs (in any framework/language) that can be used with fewer caveats?

Comment: @JoeXa Google's [Keyczar](http://keyczar.org) is meant to be a higher level API, doesn't offer you control over the initialization vector, automatically does authenticated encryption, and makes it really difficult to hard code your encryption key, and gives a mechanism for key rotation.

Comment: Or you might try and find a library for a higher level protocol such as CMS.